# TabGroupActivity resume wrong view when orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a application that use TabGroupActivity, when I change the screen orientation they resume the first view I have loaded. Example: I'm on the view 3, I rotate the phone to landscape and the first view (the loading view of the tabGroup) was resumed.

How I can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save which tab you're on in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle toSave) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(toSave);
  toSave.putString("currentTab", tabs.getCurrentTabTag());
}
```

Then restore it in `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
  super.onCreate(savedState);
  String tabTag = null;
  if (savedState != null) {
    tabTag = savedState.getString("currentTab");
  }
  ... //tab initialization code

  tabs.setCurrentTabByTag(tabTag);

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have load your view `onCreate()`, then try the following with your `TabGroupActivity`, in Manifest file:

```
  <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".TabGroupActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest for that activity set the [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) attribute. You should set the value to "orientation | keyboard | keyboardHidden", this will stop your activity from being killed and restarted thus keeping your current state.